# mySQL Like statement not working as output needed

Tags: mysql

I have item_ID column which has this number inside (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).I am running this query now

```
SELECT * FROM `coupons` WHERE item_ID like '%17%'
```

Still it's finding row. It should not find any row if item_id is parsed 17. Is there any problem with my query?

Update 
[image]

Comment: Then dont use LIKE. If you know the key and you want just that row then use `WHERE itemid = '17'`

Comment: What datatype is `item_ID`?

Comment: Use LIKE to find sub strings within a larger string. Not to select specific records

Comment: @RiggsFolly item_id column has not single specific number so I can't use itemid = '17'

Comment: @helle datatype is varchar

Comment: how many characters does it hold?

Comment: @helle varchar(5000)

Comment: Oh you mean `item_ID` contains a comma seperated list of ID's. ___Bing-Bong___ **Database design error**

Comment: @RiggsFolly :D no waaay

Comment: @SUN please post some rows out of your coupons table to you question.

Comment: @helle **Waaaay** There is one released into the wild every minute!!! :)

Comment: @helle added screenshot of my coupon table

Comment: Assuming you have a nicely formed item_ID you could try `LIKE '17,'` but this would assume you add a trailing comma on the last id in the list. Really you should throw away this database and do a quick Database Design for beginners tutorial

Comment: @RiggsFolly Should I kill my self to make this database?

Comment: Stop. See normalization.

Comment: @Barmar not sure this is a duplicate OP is asking why a coupon is found WHERE item_ID like '%17% when it does not exist in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)?

Comment: @P.Salmon His screenshot has `...` at the end. I suspect the field contains something like `,117` or `,175` further on. If he uses `FIND_IN_SET` it won't get incorrect matches like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how LIKE would be used: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

I assume your item_ID is some numeric type, right?
So you can use the `=` operator:

If it realy is varchar (which I do not recommand for an identifier variable, because of performance issues), you would use:

```
SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE item_ID = '17';
```

If you want to find IDs containing the substring `17` then your query is allright.

If you have a commaseperated list of your IDs as string in that field (which I do **not** recommand) you should try this:

```
SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE item_ID LIKE '%,17,%' OR item_ID LIKE '%,17' OR item_ID LIKE '17,%' ;
```

check your content of that `itme_ID` field. `117`, `1710`, ` etc. can be found with your query as well.

Comment: No Item_ID is not single item ID . It is collection of many ID so this can not be used

Comment: sheeeesh, please update you question and give us more details. thanks